# How to add suffix to each file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have four files in my directory that I need to moved to a new directory using command

`mv file1.txt file2.dat file3.sh dest_dir.bak`

where `dest_dir.bak` is the new directory.

Now I am to add suffix to all the files which are in this directory with `.dat`

My attempt:

`for file in *; do echo mv -- "$file" "$file.dat"; done`

But when I ran this command it has renamed all the files in the home directory with `.dat` but I need to make this changes only to the `dest_dir.bak` directory. How to achieve this?

Comment: What about `for file in dest_dir.bak/* ...`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks this should work for me. Is there any other way to remove the ```.dat``` which has applied to all the files?

Comment: Sure, `for f in *.dat; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.dat}"; done`. Check the output, and if it looks OK, remove the `echo` and re-run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered below.
But I prefer this method.

```
find . -d 1 -type f -exec mv '{}' './dest_dir.bak/{}.dat' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
for file in file*; do mv ${file} ./dest_dir.bak/${file}.dat; done
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using curly braces with variable names in your answer?

Comment: I prefer using curly braces because it is easy to read variable names.